# How to match any number of conditions with one "Then" step in Cucumber-JVM?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

In cucumber (java version), how do I match all steps with one "then" function?

For example I would like to be able to **match all the following in one function**:

```
Then the response status will be "200"
Then the response status will be "200" or "302"
Then the response status will be "200" or "302" or "404"
```

Do I need to write a matcher for each of the "or"s?

**Is there a way that I could write one matcher for all of the cases above**?

For example, how do I combine these into one function?:

```
@Then("^the response status should be \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_response_status_should_be(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("** the response status should be "+arg1);
}

@Then("^the response status should be \"([^\"]*)\" or \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_response_status_should_be_or(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("** the response status should be "+arg1+" "+arg2);
}

@Then("^the response status should be \"([^\"]*)\" or \"([^\"]*)\" or \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void the_response_status_should_be_or(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("** the response status should be "+arg1+" "+arg2+" "+arg3);
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: could there be _more_ than 3 values?

Comment: @Reimeus possibly! I could limit it to up to 3, then maybe check if each are undefined or not?

Comment: AFAIK what you are attempting is not possible in its current form as the number of step file arguments is always fixed. Therefore the option below would seem like the best option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the list of values [can grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401220/how-to-match-any-number-of-conditions-with-one-then-step-in-cucumber-jvm#comment66128822_39401220) you could map to a `List` with a feature file containing

```
...
Then the response status will be one of the following
    | response status | 
    | 200             |
    | 302             |
    | 404             |
....
```

with Cucumber code

```
@Then(^the response status will be one of the following$)
public void doResponseStuff(List<String> responses){
   // use response codes...
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the @Reimeus good answer, you also can match a `List<Integer>` in your step definition.

Feature definition:

```
...
Then the response status will be 200,302,404
...
```

Java step code:

```
@When("^the response status will be (.*)$")
public void the_response_status_should_be(List<Integer> statusList) throws Throwable {
   //...
}
```

I think both choices are valid for your requirements. Hope it helps

Comment: This is an excellent answer too! It was hard for me to choose between you two so I chose the person who answered first, but this answer will also work for my problem :) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!No worries at all. To be honest, I preffer @Reimeus answer as well, but i thought would be interesting let youk know the other choice :) Thanks for the +1

Comment: The other answer is perfect but trivial. There is also one advantage to this one: you can use it very well in scenario outlines.